# Bash mail script which asks recipient, subject and body

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email

I have a problem trying to make my own bash mail script which every time will ask to enter a recipient, subject and body in console. And then send it. Could anyone help with this? Thanks a LOT!

P.S I am using `mail` command

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Welcome to [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/)
! At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good Luck!

Comment: @RamanSailopal sorry i am newbie on stackoverflow)

Comment: Make sure you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

```
read -p "What is your subject ? " subj
read -p "What is your message? " mess
read -p "What is the recipient address? " add
grep -E '[[:alnum:]]+@[[:alnum:]]+(.[[:alnum:]]+){1,2}' <<< $add
if [[ "$?" == "0" ]
then
    echo "$mess" | mail -s "$subj" $add
else
    echo "ERROR - The recipient address is in the wrong format"
fi
```

Here we read in responses for subject, body and recipient we then check for the correct format of the email address and use the variables to send a mail if the recipient address is in the correct format. If not, show an error message.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made almost the same script but without format check

Answer (score 0):

You will use the [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) command to get user input. Hint: use the `-p` option.

Don't forget to ["quote" all your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667), especially with variables holding unknown user input.

Comment: ok, thanks, but how i can use this variables to send mail? what i need to write to use this variables in command?

Comment: You would use `echo "$body" | mail -s "$subject" "$recipient"`